# Create an ButtonClick Event in UserControl in C#

Tags: c#

I create the ButtonClick event in the UserControl below and want to handle it in a Form, but I get an error that says 'The name UserControl1.ButtonClick' does not exist in the current context.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
        public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        public event EventHandler ButtonClick;


    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ButtonClick != null)
            this.ButtonClick(this, e);
    }
```

Form:

```
        UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick);



    protected void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //handle the event
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to use the class itself instead of an instance? in the line `UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick);`

Comment: Thank you. I instantiated, but that instance couldn't even use. Both classes are public and the event is public as well. I built the UserControl1 class for sure which is in the same project as Form.

Comment: @mercredi - You really should use `var bc = this.ButtonClick; if (bc != null) bc(this, e);` rather than `if (this.ButtonClick != null) this.ButtonClick(this, e);` to invoke your events as the former is thread-safe and the latter isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Form:

```
public PatientNumber()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            userControl11.updateButton.Click += button_Click;
        }

        protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     　　　 //handle the event
        }
```

UserControl:

```
public Button btnUpdatee
{
    get
    {
        return btnUpdate;
    }
    set
    {
        btnUpdate = value;
    }
}
```

This code worked.
Thank you